# How to recreate line effect in the famous Woolmark Logo

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

How can I recreate the oddly curved line effect seen in the famous Woolmark logo in Adobe Illustrator?

Thanks in advance.

[image]tor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Woolmark Logo was [designed in 1964](http://www.logodesignlove.com/woolmark-logo). It was undoubtedly simply 'drawn' that way.

In other words, it's not a particular feature of any particular software. It's simply a design that was finely crafted by hand.

To recreate it in Illustrator, you'd do the same thing. Draw them. You could leverage some of the tools within Illustrator...such as cloning and rotating to the point where you may only need to draw one actual line, but ultimately, you'd still be constructing it 'by hand' in the form that you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Place this Image in Adobe Illustrator, use IMAGE TRACE COMMAND and Expand after that.

It will now be a vector logo with the same curve lines (if you have any doubts on how to do it you can see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rI02k4PCoOU)).